# Stop redirect to Contact us in Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, forms, contact-us

I use Magento 1.7.x version and I add Contact form in the product page as tab, everything is okay but when I press the Submit button, the contact form is redirect me to the 'contacts/index/post' and I want to remove this redirect, and after the Submit button is press to stay in the current page.

in the catalog I add this code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
      <action method="addTab" translate="title">
            <alias>contact</alias>
            <title>Contact Us</title>
            <block>core/template</block>
            <template>contacts/product_form.phtml</template>
    </action>
</block>
```

so my file now is contacts/product_form.phtml in this file I have the following code:

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                   <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

My question is:
How I can stop the redirect to contact us page after press the submit page?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to change the url where the form is posting.
You just need to change the url where it is redirecting after going to contacts/index/post.
Means you just need to replace following code in postAction:

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

with this code

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

but I dont advise to change any core file so you can rewrite the controller and change the post action according to your need.

Comment: Most welcome @Robert. :)